# Interpreting summation with fractional part?

Tags: summation, notation

This summation is obvious if k is even.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k/2} f(n)$$

How should this summation be interpreted if k is odd?

***(update)***

The context is deciding and writing a proof for the assertion that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k} f(n)$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k/2} f(n) + \sum_{n=k/2}^{k} f(n)$$

are equivalent statements.  Of course for even k, the meaning is obvious. I suspect the proof will be "proof by cases" showing that however k/2 is interpreted, the fact that it's the upper bound in the first term and the lower bound in the second term will make it equivalent to the first equation.

But, I want to make sure that I understand what the normal (if any) interpretation of k/2 in the bounds is for non-even values of k.

Comment: You should provide more context where you came acroos this "sum". Maybe it gets clearer then.

Comment: The context is simple: I was asked this question and didn't know the answer.  I expected wikipedia, etc, to clarify something like "the top bound should always be an integer" but couldn't find such a clarification, therefore I'm asking here. BTW, you put "sum" in quotation marks... is there a better way I should phrase this.

Comment: I did so because classicly the upper bound is an integer. But you could define such a sum by using measure theory (in this case the sum were an integral on a discrete measure space). But in this case there are too few details given to give that expression a meaningful value, at least in my opinion and from my point of knowlegde.

Comment: @MarkHarrison Do you have an example where you've seen such a summation; it might help provide context for what the original author intended. As it stands now, this could be viewed as anything from a blunder by the author, to a brilliant trick they are using in a proof in measure theory.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far... they've been helpful.  I filled in the context.

Comment: Is it not standard that $\sum_{i=0}^{4.5}$ means $\sum_{i=0; i++; i \le 4.5} = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor 4.5 \rfloor}= \sum_{i=0}^4$?

Comment: Btw that is NOT true if $k$ is even;  $f(k/2)$ has been added twice in the RHS but only once in the LHS.

Comment: For what it's worth, Wolfram Alpha simply takes the floor of a non-integer upper bound without any comment. I tried `Sum[n^2, {n, 1, 7/2}]`

Comment: @RobertSoupe  I don't know how standard it is to simply take the floor (or ceiling if the non integer is in the base) is, but it *should* be standard.  It just makes communication sooo much easier and it's clearly consistant.

Comment: @fleablood How often do you think this sort of thing comes up? If I was programming a computer algebra system like Mathematica, I would have to think about this sort of thing, my paycheck could depend on it. But as a mathematical dilettante, this is just a curiosity; but if I need to, I can bypass it easily enough.

Comment: It's come up for me a surprising number of times.  Thing is it's a notational headache but a conceptual triviality.  Concept is important.  Notation is not (except in the sense that poor notation leads to misconception). So I f igire it is easier to say "let the summation term be an upper bound" and be done with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you are asking is far from trivial and goes to the core of discrete mathematics,
thus deserving some dedicated space here: I'll try and summarize some major points.
The usual interpretation of such a sum  is through  [indefinte sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum).
Consider that, given $f(n)$, you know a $F(n)$ such that
$$
f(n) = F(n + 1) - F(n) = \Delta _{\,n} F(n) = \Delta _{\,n} \left( {F(n) + c} \right)
$$
Then $F(n)$ is the "anti-delta" or "Discrete Primitive" of $f(n)$
$$
F(n) + c = \Delta _{\,n} ^{ - 1} f(n) = \sum\nolimits_{\,n} {f(n)} 
$$
where $c$ is a constant.
Let's introduce this specific definition of summation
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\nolimits_{\,k\, = \,m}^{\;n} {f(k)} \quad \left| {\;{\rm integer}\,n,m} \right.\quad  = F\left( n \right) - F\left( m \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left\{ {\matrix{
   {f(m) + f(m + 1) +  \cdots  + f(n - 1)} & {\left| {\;m < n} \right.}  \cr 
   0 & {\left| {\;m = n} \right.}  \cr 
   { - \left( {f(n) + f(n + 1) +  \cdots  + f(m - 1)} \right)} & {\left| {\;n < m} \right.}  \cr 
 } } \right.\;\; =   \cr 
  &  = \left\{ {\matrix{
   {\sum\limits_{m\, \le \,k\, < \,n} {f(k)}  = \sum\limits_{m\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {f(k)} } & {\left| {\;m < n} \right.}  \cr 
   0 & {\left| {\;m = n} \right.}  \cr 
   { - \sum\limits_{n\, \le \,k\, < \,m} {f(k)}  =  - \sum\limits_{n\, \le \,k\, \le \,m - 1} {f(k)} } & {\left| {\;n < m} \right.}  \cr 
 } } \right.\;\; \cr} 
$$
and we can see that
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\nolimits_{\,k\, = \,m}^{\;n} {f(k)}  =  - \sum\nolimits_{\,k\, = \,n}^{\;m} {f(k)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\nolimits_{\,k\, = \,m}^{\;q} {f(k)}  + \sum\nolimits_{\,k\, = \,q}^{\;n} {f(k)}  = \sum\nolimits_{\,k\, = \,q}^{\;n} {f(k)}  - \sum\nolimits_{\,k\, = \,q}^{\;m} {f(k)} \quad \left| {\;{\rm integer}\,n,m,q} \right. \cr} 
$$
So, $F(n)$ exists and is defined, apart from a constant, over the definition domain of $f(n)$.
Now, if the domain of definition of $F$ extends to the reals, it comes natural to define
$$
\sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,m}^{\;x} {f(k)}  = F(x) - F(m) = \left( {F(x) + c(x)} \right) - \left( {F(m) + c(m)} \right)
$$
where, this time, we put $c(x)$ as it might actually be any periodic function of $x$ with period $1$.
If $f$ can also be extended to reals, it will be
$$
\sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,a}^{\;x} {f(k)} \quad \left| {\;\;a,x \in \;\;\mathbb{R}} \right.\quad  = F(x) - F(a) 
$$
and
$$
\sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,x}^{\;x + 1} {f(k)}  = F(x + 1) - F(x) = \Delta _{\,x} F(x) = f(x)
$$
Let's take an example to fix the concept.
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \sum\nolimits_{\,x} {\frac{1}
{x}} \, = \psi \left( x \right) + c = \frac{{\Gamma '(x)}}
{{\Gamma (x)}} + c\quad  \Rightarrow  \hfill \\
   \Rightarrow \quad \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,\,3/2} {\frac{1}
{k}}  = \sum\nolimits_{\,k\, = \,1}^{\;5/2} {\frac{1}
{k}}  = \psi \left( {5/2} \right) - \psi \left( 1 \right) = \frac{8}
{3} - 2\ln (2) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
but we can also legitimally write
$$
\sum\nolimits_{\,x} {\frac{1}
{x}} \, = \psi \left( x \right) + \sin (2\pi x)
$$
or
$$
\sum\nolimits_{\,x} {\frac{1}
{x}} \, = \psi \left( x \right) + \frac{1}
{{1 + x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor }}
$$
which implies that the value we gave to the summation above could actually be whatever else,
unless we agree to exclude the periodic component, and keep only the "smoother" component as it is normally done.
Many functions - but not all - admit a *Discrete Primitive*, i.e. a function $F(x)$ such that $f(x)=F(x+1)-F(x)$
for all the $x$ in the definition domain of $f$.
In conclusion, **the standard answer to your question is**
$$
\sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n/2} {f(k)}  = F(1 + n/2) - F(1)
$$

Concerning an intuitive blick at "what is making up the total" we have that
$$
\sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,m}^{\;x} {f(k)}  = \sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,m}^{\;\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } {f(k)}  + \sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor }^{\;x} {f(k)}  = \sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,m}^{\;\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } {f(k)}  + \sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,0}^{\;\left\{ x \right\}} {f(x + k)} 
$$
however, when the limits are $x$ and $x+m$ we obtain
$$
\sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,x}^{\;x + m} {f(k)}  = \sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,x}^{\;x + 1} {f(k)}  +  \cdots  + \sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,x + m - 1}^{\;x + m} {f(k)}  = \sum\nolimits_{j\, = \,0}^{\;m} {f(x + j)}  = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   { - \sum\limits_{m\, \leqslant \,j\, \leqslant \, - 1} {f(x + j)}  =  - \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,l\, \leqslant \, - m - 1} {f(x - l + 1)} } & {m < 0}  \\
   0 & {0 = m}  \\
   {\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,j\, \leqslant \,m - 1} {f(x + j)} } & {0 < m}  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$
If $f(x)$ is "summable on the right", that is if it exists and is finite for all the $x$ in the domain of $f$ the following limit
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{m\; \to \;\infty } \sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,x}^{\;m} {f(k)}  = \sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,x}^{\;\infty } {f(k)}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,j\, < \infty } {f(x + j)} 
$$
then we can write
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,m}^{\;x} {f(k)}  = \sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,m}^{\;\infty } {f(k)}  - \sum\nolimits_{k\, = \,x}^{\;\infty } {f(k)}  = \sum\nolimits_{j\, = \,0}^{\;\infty } {f(m + j)}  - \sum\nolimits_{j\, = \,0}^{\;\infty } {f(x + j)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\nolimits_{j\, = \,0}^{\;\infty } {\left( {f(m + j) - f(x + j)} \right)}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
which is the **Mueller's Formula**.
It goes in an analogue way if $f(x)$ is "summable on the left", and we can summarize the conclusions therefrom as
$$
\begin{gathered}
  F(x) + c = \sum\nolimits_{\,x} {f(x)}  = \Delta _{\,x} ^{ - 1} f(x) =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {f(x - (k + 1))} \quad \left| {\;f\;\text{summable}\,\text{left}} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   =  - \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {f(x + k)} \quad \left| {\;f\;\text{summable}\,\text{right}} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\nolimits_{\,k\, = \,0\;}^{\,\;\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } {f(x - (k + 1))} \quad \; + \Delta _{\,x} ^{ - 1} f(\left\{ x \right\})\quad \left| {\;f\;\text{summable}\,\text{left}\,\text{and/or}\,\text{right}} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\nolimits_{\,j\, = \,0\;}^{\,\;\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } {f(\left\{ x \right\} + j)} \quad \;\;\quad  + \Delta _{\,x} ^{ - 1} f(\left\{ x \right\})\quad \left| {\;f\;\text{summable}\,\text{left}\,\text{and/or}\,\text{right}} \right. \hfill \
\end{gathered} 
$$
where the 3rd = 4th line can be easily derived from the precedent.
The term $\Delta _{\,x} ^{ - 1} f(\left\{ x \right\})$ is a period-1 function , which normally does not have a simple closed form
and which is cancelling an equivalent component implicit in the first term. So if taken out, leaves a *non-standard* $F(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

I've changed my mind

$\sum_{i=0}^k \ne \sum_{i=0}^{k/2} + \sum_{i=k/2}^k$.

If $k$ is even the $k/2$ term is added twice in the sum on the RHS.

If $k$ is odd then the RHS second sum starts on a fraction and *every* term is a fraction.

To correct this the following is always true:

$\sum_{i=0}^k \ne \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} + \sum_{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor + 1}^k$.

That should be clear.

====somewhat wrong answer below ====

it has to be agreed upon by convention that if $m \not \in \mathbb N$ what $\sum_{i=0}^m$ *means*. As $i$ will *never* equal $m$.

I think it is standard convention that $\sum_{i=k}^m$ actually means $\sum_{i \ge k;i++; i \le m}$.  Or in other words $\sum_{i=k}^m$ = $\sum_{i=\lceil k \rceil}^{\lfloor m \rfloor}$

Actually if $k$ is even that is NOT true as $f(k/2)$ is added twice.  If $k$ is odd it IS  true as $\sum_{i=0}^{k/2} = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}$ and $\sum_{i=k/2}^{k} = \sum_{i = \lceil k/2 \rceil}^{k}$.  If $k$ is even $\lfloor k/2 \rfloor =  \lceil k/2 \rceil$ and the term is counted twice.  If $k$ is odd it is not.

So the statement is true if $k$ is *ODD* and it is *FALSE* if $k$ is even.

Comment: There *is* the possibility that when I said "I think it is standard convention" that I might have really meant "this is how *I* interpret it because it makes just such problems like this sooo much easier but no-one else on the planet does and you have to twist yourself into knots to actually express what you are trying ot say and I find that sooooo annoying as it'd just be easier if other people just did it my way."

Comment: Actually, I am wrong about if the base ($\sum_{i= 4.5}$).  It doesn't mean to take the ceiling.  It means that *every* term is $.5 + integer$.  But if we write the base to take the ceiling that would more accurately express what we wish to say.

Comment: ... so on the third hand, I guess the expression is never true.  If $k$ is even $f(k/2)$ is counted twice.  If $k$ is odd the second base starts at a fraction.  But if you rewrite with ceilings and floors the equation is obvious and trivial.

Comment: Have a look to my answer below to try and fix your ideas

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this summation should be interpreted as invalid if $k$ is odd. But as the various commenters have already noted, the problem is bypassed easily enough by the use of the floor function.

The notational convention for iterations like $$\sum_{n = \textrm{start}}^{\textrm{end}} f(n)$$ is that both $\textrm{start}$ and $\textrm{end}$ are integers, that the step is $1$ and that $\textrm{start} \leq \textrm{end}$.

What happens when you need a step other than $1$? You can do something like $$\sum_{n = \textrm{start}}^{\textrm{end}} f(10n)$$ or $$\sum_{n = \textrm{start}}^{\textrm{end}} f\left(\frac{n}{10}\right).$$

The reason I bring both of these up is that technically the step is $1$ even though in a computer program you might specifically write something like `step = 10` or `step = 0.1`.

None of these options in mathematical notation explicitly allow for $\textrm{start}$ orr $\textrm{end}$ to be anything other than integers. To assume that non-integer values are implicitly allowed, or to assume that they will be interpreted in the same particular way that you intend them to be, is a needless sacrifice of clarity, in my opinion.

Just because a couple of people tell you that it's interpreted $\textrm{end} = \lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor$ for one and $\textrm{start} = \lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor + 1$ for the other does not guarantee that everyone will see it that way, at first anyway. In fact, one of the answerers seems to think that if $n = \frac{k}{2}$ is not an integer, then *that* is the starting value but the step is still $1$, e.g., $n$ takes on these values:  $$\frac{k}{2}, \frac{k}{2} + 1, \frac{k}{2} + 2, \ldots, k - \frac{1}{2} \textrm{ or } k + \frac{1}{2}.$$ For example, if $k = 7$, would we have $\textrm{end} = 6.5$ or $\textrm{end} = 7.5$?

We can certainly argue and argue that one choice is more valid than the other, but do you care more about being right on this issue or do you care more about getting your point across? There's just too much potential for ambiguity, and it can all be avoided by the simple use of the floor or ceiling function as needed.