# How can I write this sum compactly?

Tags: summation

I found this sum while trying solving the Hermite differential equation by series.

$$x+x*(4-x)+x*(4-x)*(8-x)+..... $$

Comment: Well, it never converges (except when $x$ is a multiple of $4$.)

Answer (score 3):

I think this works:

$x*(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n(4k-x))$

Or maybe (apparently on a technicality)

$-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\prod_{k=0}^n(4k-x)$

Comment: That's missing the very first term $x\,$. You probably want the sum to start at $n=0$ with the convention that an empty product is considered to equal $1\,$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379699/summation-and-product-bounds) why).

Comment: fixed :). Any suggestions to make it more compact?

Comment: What about the second one?

Comment: What I meant is: $$x \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n(4k-x)$$

Comment: Do the new ones work?

Comment: First one is missing a parenthesis. The second one does technically work.

Comment: so $\prod_{k=0}^0 f(x) = 1$ always? Is that why? If not, I get that at n = 0, the entire thing gives $x$.

Comment: No, but $\,\prod_{k=\color{red}{1}}^0 a_k=1$ which is the multiplicative identity, like $\,\sum_{k=1}^0 a_k=0$ which is the additive identity.

Comment: Then I'm not sure why the answer doesn't work. Could you write out the first couple terms?

Comment: It *does* work, read my comment again. Reason why I said that it `*technically* works` is that I find the alternative a bit easier to follow, where you factor out the $x\,$, instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works:
$$x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}4^n\frac{\Gamma(1-\frac{x}{4}+n)}{\Gamma(1-\frac{x}{4})}$$

The fraction is effectively doing $(1 - \frac{x}{4})(2 - \frac{x}{4})\dots (n - \frac{x}{4})$, which when combined with the $4^n$ gives $4(1 - \frac{x}{4})\cdot4(2 - \frac{x}{4})\cdot\dots \cdot4(n - \frac{x}{4})$ or $(4 - x)(8 - x)\dots (4n - x)$.

Only $x$ is missing for every term, but that can be put outside the sum. In fact, the $\Gamma(1-\frac{x}{4})$ can be put outside the sum, giving:

$$\frac{x}{\Gamma(1-\frac{x}{4})}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}4^n\Gamma(1-\frac{x}{4}+n)$$